# SVN Error - 501 Not Implemented Commit Failed

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I have a folder in a repository that cannot commit and even parent folders cannot commit. This happened several weeks ago, then worked, then on the blink again. I have cleared my authentication cache and no help. I can still work with other trunks but not this one and the error message does not help me where to go. I have done Clean Up. I have created a new directory from VisualSVN from the repository and same problem. Would you have any suggestions? Can I nuke the .svn folder and help? I don't want to start with a new repo because we have TeamCity integrated and watching. Help and thanks in advance! 
Doug

**Error: Commit failed (details follow):

Error: Server sent unexpected return value (501 Not Implemented) in response to

Error: PROPFIND request for '/svn/MAHCP/trunk/src/RssaSolution/Mahcp.Rssa'**

I posted to SVNForum as well but has anyone else had this crazy situation!

Comment: It would be helpful to know the Apache/mod_svn/svn versions, as returning "not implemented" ... well, looks like meaning "not implemented".  I've had problems with svn over https:// and self-signed certificates.  Do you use such a beast, maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was an old outdated URL to the repository trunk.  I wish the error was a bit more descriptive.  Thanks guys....if I had more reputation I'd grant you both points!

Answer (score 7):

That's usually a proxy or virus scanner/firewall rejecting DAV requests (PROPFIND is not a 'normal' http request but used with DAV).

So: check your proxy and/or virus scanner/firewall and configure them to allow DAV requests.

Also, sometimes it help to use https instead of http so that those apps can't check the network traffic anymore and interfere with it.

Comment: thanks stefan....we are using https but will check the DAV piece and let you know

Comment: Proxy issue is what I came across regarding this problem

Answer (score 2):

The answer was that the svn server URL had been changed previously and then when trying to check it back in it would error.  The trick then was to nuke the .svn folders, pull down fresh and then copy over with my new changes.  I wish the error message had been better.

Answer (score 0):

If u use a subclipse try to change the SVN interface client from JavaHL to SVNKid

Answer (score 0):

Check also to see if mod_security was recently installed. At least on CentOS, its default configuration does not have the lines necessary to allow SVN.

In `/etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/modsecurity_crs_30_http_policy.conf`, I put this in the *allowed request methods* section:

```
SecRule REQUEST_METHOD "^(PROPFIND|PROPPATCH)$" allow
SecRule REQUEST_METHOD "^(REPORT|OPTIONS)$" allow
SecRule REQUEST_METHOD "^(MKACTIVITY|CHECKOUT)$" allow
SecRule REQUEST_METHOD "^(PUT|DELETE|MERGE)$" allow
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with another client until I've discovered `Anonymous lock creation is not allowed.` message in /var/log/apache2/error.log on the server. Make sure the client doesn't connect to the server anonymously.

Answer (score -1):

delete the folder 
    /home/user/.subversion,

then restart the IDE or svn.