# SVN COPY error: 501 Method Not Implemented

Tags: c#, svn, visualsvn-server, sharpsvn

We've been using VisualSVN (standard edition) for a few years without any problems. We have a C# application which stores data in SVN. It uses SharpSvn (https://sharpsvn.open.collab.net) library for SVN access. Occasionally, the application executes a server-side SVN COPY command (SharpSvn's "RemoteCopy") to create a branch based on a series of existing in the repository files.

We recently updated VisualSVN from version 2.5.2 to 3.2.2 and also purchased a license to unlock enterprise features of the product. We enabled Integrated Windows Authentication, but also kept Basic Authentication for backward compatibility.

After running for a week without any problems (performing only reads from SVN), our application tried to perform the copy for the first time, and it failed with the following error complaining about one of the files that had to be copied:

"COPY request on '/svn/repository/!svn/rvr/12345/trunk/file.xml' failed: 501 Method Not Implemented"

The server log reveals the following:

```
Level,Date and Time,Source,Event ID,Task Category
Error,2015-03-03 9:37:26 AM,VisualSVN Server 3.2,1001,Apache,"Multi-author commits not supported.  [501, #175002] [client 192.168.1.100]"
Error,2015-03-03 9:37:26 AM,VisualSVN Server 3.2,1001,Apache,"Could not fetch resource information.  [501, #0] [client 192.168.1.100]"
Error,2015-03-03 9:37:26 AM,VisualSVN Server 3.2,1001,Apache,"SSPI Challenge failed: The token supplied to the function is invalid [client 192.168.1.100]"
Error,2015-03-03 9:37:21 AM,VisualSVN Server 3.2,1001,Apache,"SSPI Challenge failed: The token supplied to the function is invalid [client 192.168.1.100]"
```

After restarting VisualSVN service, the command completed without any problems. This had never happened before with the older versions of VisualSVN.

This is how we create a branch using SharpSvn:

```
    private static void Branch(ICollection<SvnUriTarget> sources, Uri targetUri, string comment, string userName, string password)
    {
        if (sources == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("sources");
        if (targetUri == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("targetUri");
        if (comment.IsNullEmptyOrSpaces()) throw new ArgumentNullException("comment");
        if (userName.IsNullEmptyOrSpaces()) throw new ArgumentNullException("userName");
        if (password.IsNullEmptyOrSpaces()) throw new ArgumentNullException("password");

        using (var client = new SvnClient())
        {
            client.Authentication.Clear();
            client.Authentication.DefaultCredentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
            client.Authentication.SslServerTrustHandlers += (sender, e) => { e.AcceptedFailures = e.Failures; e.Save = true; };

            SvnCommitResult commitResult;
            if (!client.RemoteCopy(sources, targetUri, new SvnCopyArgs { CreateParents = true, LogMessage = comment }, out commitResult))
                throw new ApplicationException("Failed to create tag/branch in Repository");
        }
    }
```

In our application, we are still using Basic Authentication, and credentials are explicitly passed to every SharpSvn call. The application requests credentials from the user, and then it uses these credentials to perform a single call of the "Branch" method. 
Two different users tried to do this using their own credentials on two different machine with the same result. Only restart of VisualSVN service fixed the problem. I'm worried that this problem may come back again...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/561855/62576

Comment: @Ken White: I've seen this, and I don't know how it's related to my problem even though the error message is the same.

Comment: Did you make any customizations in httpd-custom.conf? Which version of SharpSvn are you using?

Comment: @ivanzhakov: No, we didn't touch httpd-custom.conf. We use SharpSvn version 1.8008.3178.19, but we also tried 1.8009.3299.43 with the same result.

Comment: @kazakm May be you have cached credentials in %APPDATA%\Subversion\auth? As far I understand log messages the situation is the following: first requests performed using one credentials, second using another (cached?) credentials.  Did you have any related errors in Security logs?

Comment: @IvanZhakov 

I provided more info in my original post, and I also included the complete implementation of the "Branch" method.
The application is running on machines which also have TortoiseSVN installed, and the users access the repository using both apps. They also tend to "save" credentials in TortoiseSVN (a checkbox in the credentials dialog). 

Unfortunately, I no longer see old security log messages. They have been erased.

Comment: @kazakm See my answer: basically operation still performed using credentials of logged on user since integrated authentication considered with higher priority.

Comment: @IvanZhakov But why did it work after VisualSVN service restart? It should have kept on failing... Also, other operations involved accessing SVN using the same authentication mechanism had been working fine even before the restart.

Comment: @kazakm Btw, how many files are you trying to copy? I'm asking because I found another related bug that svn cannot commit more than 10K of files using NTLM.

Comment: @IvanZhakov In this particular case, the application tried to copy about 1800 files.

Comment: @kazakm On more clarification: did you copy one directory with 1800 files or `sources` parameter has 1800 entries?

Comment: @IvanZhakov it tried to copy 1800 individual "sources"

Answer (score 1):

You should disable SharpSvn (and Subversion) to use Integrated Authentication ('ntlm' and 'negotiate') if you're going to specify credentials for operation.

Try add code like this:

```
client.Configuration.SetOption("servers", "global", "http-auth-types", "basic");
```

Probably this is a bug in Subversion, SharpSvn or serf, but proposed workaround should work.